# Wait a minute...Where did he go? (part 1)

Tags: cipher

A secret person hid three rolls of paper under my bed

First roll: you'll find my country only if you solve this puzzle

> '3rd of 2, 1st of 2, 2nd of 6, 3rd of 2, 1st of 3, 3rd of 2'

Second roll: you'll find my province only if you solve this puzzle

> '17th, 21st, 5th, 2nd, 5th, 3rd'

Third roll: you'll find my city only if you solve this puzzle

> 'XIII, XV, XIV, XX, XVIII, V, I, XII'

Let's start the journey of finding him!

Comment: RE "comment for hints": Puzzles where the intent is to provide more information upon request (interactive puzzles) are not acceptable here; puzzles should provide all the necessary information within the question itself. See the wiki for [tag:semi-interactive-puzzle]

Comment: This seems very low-effort -- a "where in the world..."-style puzzle series sounds like a nice idea, but I'd recommend making the puzzles more in-depth in the future. (And please, tag them correctly.)

Comment: I think you have two references to '3rd of 2' that should actually be '1st of 2'... (the later two)

Comment: @bobble Given no request for additional information was made (unless question was edited?), and the puzzle was still solved, it doesn't appear it was intentionally an interactive puzzle.  All necessary information was given.

Comment: No request was made because the puzzle was extremely simple and easy. That doesn't change the fact that the original version of this puzzle said "comment for hints", clearly indicating that they were fine with some level of interactivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is

> talking about letters on a phone keypad. If you take the given letter on the given key, it spells `CANADA`.

The second is

> just A=1, B=2, ..., Z=26. The numbers given spell `QUEBEC`.

The third is

> also just A=1, B=2, ..., Z=26, but this time in Roman numerals. The numbers given spell `MONTREAL`.